# How can I open a specific file with this in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that has a list and a button. When you press the button, I want it to write the contents of a specific file(scores.txt) in the list. 
This is my code now but with this I can choose the file, but it doesn't open it automatically:

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Documents(*.txt)|*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
           string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
           List<string> list = new List<string>();
           foreach (string s in lines)
           {
                 list.Add(Convert.ToString(s));
                 listReadFile.Items.Add(s);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't open it automatically"?

Comment: I want the button to open the scores.txt file. With this code it lets me choose which file to open, but I don't want that. I want it to open the file directly.

Comment: Programs do what you tell them to. If you don't want the file picker, don't use it.

Comment: Open it up in the list. It's for a Hangman game and I have a file that has players' scores in it. I want the button to open that file in the list (like right now, but without the option to choose).

Comment: Do you mean you want to view the contents of the file? That is not the same as "open" the file.

Comment: Anett by using the open file dialog, you chose to give the user the ability to choose. Its whole purpose is to let the user select a file and then it will return the filename to you via the FileName property. You have explicitly written the application to let the user choose.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the mixup. I want to view the contents of the file in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hard code the filename.

```
string fileName = @"c:\data\score.txt";
enter code here
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in lines)
{
     list.Add(Convert.ToString(s));
     listReadFile.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That'll be because you're using an OpenFileDialog.

If you want it to open a file automatically, replace `ofd.FileName` with the path string of the file you want it to open.

As a side note, I recommend adding this string into your application config, instead of hard-coding it directly.